# Can't enable Wifi in HP Envy with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, hp

I couldn't enable Wifi in my Hp Envy laptop with Ubuntu 14.04. This version is newly installed.

I did try out most of the solutions listed here and they didn't work for me.

This is my output of rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

2: phy0: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Did you look into device manager: additional drivers tab? See if listed there and turn it on

Comment: Have you tried reebooting and seeing if you internet comes on???

Answer (score 1):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: Also answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866320/hp-17-x061nr-cannot-enable-wireless